# Exercise VIII.3.9 in Hungerford's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I am working on the following exercise (Exercise VIII.3.9 in Hungerford's *Algebra*).

> Let $R$ be Noetherian and let $B$ be an $R$-module. 
>   If $P$ is a prime ideal such that $P=\text{ann }x$ for some nonzero $x\in B$ (see Exercise VIII.3.7), 
>   then $P$ is called an associated prime of $B$.
>
> (a) If $B\neq 0$, 
>   then there exists an associated prime of $B$.
>   [*Hint:* use Exercise VIII.3.8.]
>
> (b) If $B\neq 0$ and $B$ satisfies the ascending chain condition on submodules, 
>   then there exist prime ideals $P_1, ..., P_{r-1}$ and a sequence of submodules $B=B_1\supseteq B_2\supseteq \cdots \supseteq B_r=0$ such that $B_i/B_{i+1}\cong R/P_i$ for each $i<r$.

My Solution:
By (a), 
there exists an associated prime $P_1=\text{ann }x$ of $B$.
Set $B=B_1=Rx$ and $B_2=0$.
Then $B_1/B_2=Rx/0\cong Rx\cong R/\text{ann }x=R/P_1$.

**My Question:**
I am wondering why we need the ascending chain condition on submodules of $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to just set $B=B_1=Rx$: what if $B\neq Rx$?  What you can do is set $Rx$ to be the *last* submodule in the chain before $0$ (i.e., $B_{r-1}$).  You'll have to then iterate the construction to climb your way up to the whole module $B$, though, and you need to use the ascending chain condition to guarantee that you reach it in finitely many steps.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for pointing my mistake out. I have found a solution at here (Theorem 1.5.10) https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg1.pdf